# Onclick Button Change AngularUI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to make 6 buttons that are selectable. I'm having trouble adding more than two. The third button is selecting other buttons and also the buttons are deselecting themselves when clicked twice. Which is undesired. It's a mess. Can anyone help me sort this out?
Here's my code:

```
    <div ng-app="plunker">
        <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
            <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-primary':isUploadActive}" ng-click="toggleActive1()">Upload</button>

            <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-primary':isDownloadActive}" ng-click="toggleActive2()">Download</button>        
        </div>    
    </div>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.button1Active = false;
    $scope.button2Active = false;
        $scope.button3Active = false;
            $scope.button4Active = false;
                $scope.button5Active = false;
                    $scope.button6Active = false;

    $scope.toggleActive1 = function() {
        if($scope.button2Active) {
            $scope.button2Active = !$scope.button2Active;
        }
        $scope.button1Active = !$scope.button1Active;
    };

    $scope.toggleActive2 = function() {    
        if($scope.button1Active) {
            $scope.button1Active = !$scope.button1Active;
        }
        $scope.button2Active = !$scope.button2Active;
    };
  $scope.toggleActive3 = function() {    
        if($scope.button3Active) {
            $scope.button3Active = $scope.button3Active;
        }
        $scope.button2Active = !$scope.button2Active;
         $scope.button1Active = !$scope.button1Active;
          $scope.button4Active = !$scope.button4Active;
           $scope.button5Active = !$scope.button5Active;
            $scope.button6Active = !$scope.button6Active;
    };
});



<div id="contentDiv">

   <div ng-app="plunker">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-primary':button1Active}" ng-click="toggleActive1()">Upload</button>

        <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-primary':button2Active}" ng-click="toggleActive2()">Download</button>        
         <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-primary':button3Active}" ng-click="toggleActive3()">Purchased</button>   
    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yikes! that is a bit messy. I made a fiddle that seems to do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/qwah3/

Basically I just give the controller one scoped object that holds the active button, and each button just checks against that value:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.active = { val : '' };
  $scope.Activate = function(buttonVal) {
    $scope.active.val = buttonVal;
  };
}
```

That means each button can just be like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{'btn-primary':active.val == 'Download'}"
        ng-click="Activate('Download')">Download</button>
```

You could even turn the button into a directive to make it even easier.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks alot! I've been trying to figure this out for days.